# skip error rows from flat file in ssis

Tags: ssis, bulkinsert, business-intelligence, flat-file, dft

I am trying to load data from a flat file. The file is around 2.5 GB in size and row count is close to billion. I am using a flat file source inside DFT. Few rows inside the file does not follow the column pattern, for example there is a extra delimiter or say text qualifier as value of one column. I want to skip those rows and load rest of the rows which has correct format. I am using SSIS 2014. Flat file source inside DFT is failing. I have set alwaysCheckforrowdelimiter property to false but still does not work. Since the file is too huge manually opening and changing is not possible. Kindly help.

Comment: If this is a one off I suggest you use a script (VBScript, Powershell, whatever) to search through the file and clean it beforehand.

Comment: Thanks..but script for a file containing close to billion rows is time consuming. This is going to be part of a daily scheduled job and need to complete within a certain time.

Comment: Are you sure it will be time consuming? for a billion rows it might take maybe half an hour max perhaps? The problem with doing it in SSIS is if you have too many delimiters it might not recognise it - it might just shuffle the fields left 1 position. You might want to consider it anyway.

Comment: Yes..it is taking around one and half hours..and the job needs to complete in 2 hours..30 min is enough for other parts of the job to run..because of this constraint i am looking for options like if we can ignore or redirect problematic rows.

Comment: I've never been able to get SSIS to recognise and ignore malformed rows. Not to say it can't, just that I've usually given up first.

Comment: On the Flatfile Source component, have you tried [redirecting error rows](http://www.techbrothersit.com/2013/07/ssis-how-to-redirect-invalid-rows-from.html)?   What is the count of error rows to non-error rows?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same idea as Nick.McDermaid but I can maybe help you a bit more.
You can clean your file with a regular expression. (In a script)

You just need to define a regex to match lines with the number of delimiter you want. Other lines should be deleted.

Here is a visual example executed in Notepad++

[Notepad++ Example screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8yOBL.png)

Here is the pattern used for my example:

```
^[A-Z]*;[A-Z]*;[A-Z]*;[A-Z]*$
```

And the data sample:

```
AA;BB;CC;DD
AA;BB;CC;DD
AA;BB;CC;DD;EE
AA;BB;CC;DD
AA;BB;CC
AA;BB;CC;DD
AA;BB;CC;DD
```

You can try it on line: https://regex101.com/r/PIYIcY/1

Regards,
Arnaud